# I would like to install Linux Mint on a separate hard drive than my windows installation on the same computer

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot

I would like to install Mint on an empty hard drive on my computer that has Windows 7 installed on it as the main drive. It would seem that this is not difficult but having tried this several months ago I got poor results. Now I have some more time and would like to try again with guidance.

I have a UEFI enabled motherboard. Regardless, I would like the end result to be when I turn on the computer, an option appears as to which of the two OS's, Windows 7 or Mint, to boot to. I don't mind if it is grub or Windows Boot manager.

Answer (score 5):

Just install the Mint CD and boot it, then select Install Linux Mint from the desktop.

After selecting language and confirmation that  you have enough drive space available and an Internet connection you will get to the "Installation type" screen. There select 'Something else', as the default (Install Linux Mint alongside Windows 7) will shrink your Windows NTFS partition on the first disc to make space for Mint.

In the next screen select the new drive (probably /dev/sdb):[image]

Select <kbd>New Partition Table</kbd> and confirm, then select the "Free Space" and <kbd>+</kbd>, to create a swap space at the end of the new drive (I usually take 1-2 times the memory space for swap):
[image]

Select the free space again and <kbd>+</kbd> and create a root partition '/' in the rest of the disc:

[image]

After that you can install. The only thing that will change on the /dev/sda drive is that it will boot into grub and there default to booting Mint. If you don't want that, change the device for bootloader installation before selecting <kbd>Install Now</kbd> and change the drive. If you do that you have to use BIOS functionality to boot Linux Mint, or make the boot process of Windows 7 multiboot

I would go with the default, but that requires to have the new drive to be available in order to start Windows, unless you first restore the MBR. So if the new drive is an external USB, then that is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great!  Originally, it kept trying to install it to my Windows partition.